# Distribution of $Y_n(\omega) = \sin(2\pi n \omega)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, density-function

I want to find the distribution of $$Y_n(\omega) = \sin(2\pi n \omega)$$
on the probability space $(]0,1[, \mathcal B(]0,1[), \lambda|_{]0,1[})$ for $n\in \mathbb N$.

Let $X$ ~ $\text{Unif}_{]0,1[}. $We have $$f_{Y_n}(y) =  f_X\left (\frac{\arcsin(y)}{2 \pi n} \right)\frac{d}{dy}\frac{\arcsin(y)}{2 \pi n} = \mathbb 1_{]0,1[} \frac{1}{2 \pi n \sqrt{1-y²}}$$
but integrating that over $]0,1[$ gives $\frac{1}{4n}$ and not $1$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $Y_n$ is not a one-to-one function of $X.$ The change-of-variables formula assumes that it is. Try computing the PDF of a square of a normal RV this way... you will get an answer that is wrong by a factor of two. (also, incidentally you should be going from $-1$ to $1$ here, even if the formula were right)

Comment: I assumed that it was an issue with injectivity... So how do I go about this? I tried to compute the CDF by hand but get the same problem.

Comment: At each point of $(-1,1)$ you need to sum over all $x$ that map to it. Here this is not so hard cause of symmetry. There are $2n$ contributions, all the same, so just multiply bu $2n.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\P}{\mathbb P}$You are considering a probability space with the lebesgue measure. Then you can find the CDF "manually". The CDF is:
$$\P(Y_n\leq z)= \frac{\arcsin(z)}{\pi}+\frac{1}{2}$$
How? Let $z\geq 0$. We first write $$\P(Y_n\leq z)=\P(Y_n<0)+\P(0\leq Y_n\leq z) $$ Finding $\{0\leq Y_n\leq z\}$ is finding $\omega\in (0,1)$ such that $0\leq\sin(2\pi n \omega)\leq z$. You have all numbers $\omega$ such that $0<2\pi n \omega \leq \arcsin(z)$. That means  $\omega \in (0, \arcsin(z)/(2\pi n)]$. But a simple reasoning tells us that we have $2n$ intervals such that the inequality holds and they all have the same measure as $\lambda( (0, \arcsin(z)/(2\pi n)])$.  That gave us $\P(0< Y_n\leq z) $. Now notice that $Y_n$ is negative with probability $1/2$, that gives us $\P(Y_n<0) =1/2$. 
That gives us the desired result.

With a similar reasoning, we can get the CDF for $z<0$ which I leave it up to you. What might help is the properties of the sine functions and drawing the sine will *almost surely* help.